# apt-get update not working apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation

Tags: apt, 18.04, updates, repository, proxy

```
root@bgworker2:~# apt update
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 103.111.180.34 8082]
Err:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Invalid response from proxy: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required  Mime-  X-iboss-Error: ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0  Proxy-Authenticate: Basic realm="ibolive     [IP: 103.111.180.34 8082]
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 103.111.180.34 8082]
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 103.111.180.34 8082]
Err:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  407  Proxy Authentication Required [IP: 103.111.180.34 8082]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no lo
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  40
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa
E: The repository 'http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease'
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRel
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InR

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disa
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta
root@bgworker2:~#
a
root@bgworker2:~#

a
root@bgworker2:~#
```

Comment: Try using another repo. `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Start by removing the docker line from the sources list. Try again after removing it.

Comment: @David i have tried by removing the docker line but same its not working

Comment: @Nithin i think you need proxy environment, run `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf` and add lines `Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyhost:port/";
Acquire::https::Proxy "https://username:password@proxyhost:port/";`